# How to convert a type to enum

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, enums

I'm trying to get an enum from a type , I'll explain, I have this enums (I used the String Enumerations) which are explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11130/String-Enumerations-in-C).

```
public enum ENUM1
{
    [StringValue("CodeIP597")] Code = 1,
    [StringValue("InfoYes")] Info = 3
}

public enum ENUM2
{
    [StringValue("CodeNoIP")] Code = 1,
    [StringValue("Info95p")] Info = 3
}
```

the method "General" is this:

```
private static void General(Type enumType)
{
   var Enu = enumType.toEnum();  //i want something like this
   Console.WriteLine(StringEnum.GetStringValue(Enu.Code));           
}
```

I have a lot of equals enums **each of these always contains the attribute "Code" and "Info"**, so i want that for every enumType that i put as a parameter, in the variable console return me the String Value.

For example : 
if i call this method

```
General(typeof(ENUM1));
```

the console will be :
CodeIP597

if i call this method

```
General(typeof(ENUM2));
```

the console will be :
CodeNoIP

How could i do? Thanks to all in advance

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using enums instead of say, an abstract base class and subclasses that define these values?

Comment: No, I'm a beginner and i want to learn. If there is another method to do this,maybe more efficient, i would be great.

Comment: Great attitude! I'll be happy to toss together some alternative on my work break. In the mean time, why not try something yourself, maybe check out "interfaces" or "inheritance", see if you can hack something out, maybe even post a new question with your attempts if something isn't quite working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your attribute looks something like this:

```
public class StringValue : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public StringValue(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then you'll have to use reflection to pull out the attribute and its value since there is no relation between your enums besides their value names:

```
private static void General(Type enumType)
{
    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Not an enum type");

    var values = enumType.GetFields();

    var code = values.First(f => f.Name == "Code");
    var info = values.First(f => f.Name == "Info");

    string codeString = code.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<StringValue>().First().Name;
    string infoString = info.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<StringValue>().First().Name;

    Console.WriteLine(codeString);
    Console.WriteLine(infoString);
}
```

It's not exactly the same as what you have in terms of output, but demonstrates how to get your string values. You may also need to add additional checks that they're the types you expect or have the attributes you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your are best of using a method called enum.GetValues();

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `GetStringValue()` in the code project link you shared, the Enum value is converted to a string before it is processed. You could rewrite `GetStringValue()` to accept a `Type` and a `string` rather than a typed enum value:

```
public static string GetStringValue(Type enumType, string valueStr)
{
    //Look for our 'StringValueAttribute' 
    //in the field's custom attributes
    FieldInfo fi = enumType.GetField(valueStr);
    StringValueAttribute[] attrs = 
       fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (StringValueAttribute), 
                               false) as StringValueAttribute[];
    if (attrs.Length > 0)
    {
        return attrs[0].Value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I removed the cache since that's not included inside the function but that should be an easy task to reintroduce.